# Duplice post with standard WP loop - fixed by using query_posts() instead

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts

I have an `index.php` file on a website designated as the blog page. I have an `archive.php` file which handles all the subsequent category pages.

I ran into an issue on the archive page, where for one of the categories the first post title would show as the same as the last post title.

Example:
Let's say we're on the aforementioned archive page: `xxx.com/category/water/`

The posts would show like this:

- Lorem Ipsum
- bla
- bla bla
- test post
- Lorem Ipsum <-- same title and post as the first one on this list.

The query looked like this (code is in Jade, principle is the same):

```
    - $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    - $cat_slug = $category -> slug;
    - $cat_name = $category -> name;

    :php
        $cat_arg = array(
            'category_name' => $cat_slug,              
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'hide_empty' => false
        );
    - $cat_loop = new WP_Query($cat_arg);

    div(class="posts")
        - if ( $cat_loop -> have_posts() ) :
            - while( $cat_loop -> have_posts() ) : $cat_loop -> the_post();

                ...

            - endwhile;
        - endif;
        - wp_reset_postdata();
```

I didn't see anything obviously wrong with this loop.

I was able to fix the issue by rewriting the above query like this:

```
    - global $wp_query;
    - $defaults = $wp_query->query_vars;

    - $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    - $cat_slug = $category->slug;
    - $cat_name = $category->name;

    - $args = array('category_name'  => $cat_slug);
    - $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    - query_posts($args);

    div(class="posts")
        - if ( have_posts() ) :;
            - while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                ...

            - endwhile;
            - wp_reset_postdata();
```

My question: Why did this fix it, or rather, why did the previous loop not work, and how could I have made the initial loop work? What could have caused the data to query and show incorrectly?

Comment: You should never use `query_posts`, it is ***extreme*** bad practice and is the cause of multiple common problems. How is Jade templating implemented? Are you sure this isn't because of Jade templating? Have you confirmed this happens in normal standard PHP?

Comment: The original index.php made use of a standard loop. I had to exclude two of the categories so had to make a custom query. Couldn't successfully exclude the two so had to resort to the solution with query posts. Jade transforms the code into regular PHP; confirmed not working if written in plain PHP. Any ideas how to fix otherwise?

Comment: if you need to modify the main query you should use `pre_get_posts`, throwing the main query away then creating a second new query is slow and causes lots of problems, e.g. multiple pagination issues. Also, `wp_reset_postdata` goes inside the if statement, not outside it

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: you could probably try calling `wp_reset_query()` or `wp_reset_postdata()` before you call the `new WP_Query`. But if the reset works, then that indicates a different issue that should be resolved instead of doing the reset.

Comment: I've tried both of these, as well as in combination, and it didn't resolve the issue. Feel free to update if anything else comes to mind. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: How about common troubleshooting like deactivating plugins? Have you tried doing so? Also, the last post, is it just the post title that's same as the first post or the permalink (and other data) also the same as the first post's? And despite I'm not positive about this, you could also try adding `'suppress_filters' => true` in your `WP_Query` args. And btw, `hide_empty` is not a default arg for `WP_Query`..